# Why was a "very low quality" flag disputed on an answer proposing an absolutely horrible practice?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I flagged this answer as "very low quality" because it's proposing a terrible idea:

---

[Determine if code is running as part of a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167617/determine-if-code-is-running-as-part-of-a-unit-test/20969137#20969137)

[image]

---

I can accept that the flag was disputed, but I honestly don't understand why.

Personally, if I saw someone writing code like this I'd actually hit them in the neck and tell them to get sober.

Is it just being left out there to stand out as a bad example for people who are trying to learn something?

Comment: No matter how bad it is, if it's an answer(that isnt spam, a reiteration of the question, or some other nonsense, ofcourse), it shouldn't be deleted. Downvote it to oblivion, yes. Delete it, no.

Comment: VLQ means that the post should be deleted immediately. There is nothing about that which meets that definition.

Comment: Review link: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12307285

Comment: @Patrice I don't know. That's like if someone asks you "How do i get rid of the shoes on my leg?" and you're telling them "Well you can saw off your feet - Yeah it works... but really...

Comment: Flags should not be used to get rid of wrong/incorect/partial/incomplete answers.  Flags should be used for answers that do not even attempt to answer the question, is complete gibberish, offensive or spam.

Comment: @Dbl Then you can downvote it.  That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: @Dbl 100% with you. I prefer my feet on me. But doesnt change the fact it IS an answer. A VERY bad one, but an answer. The VLQ flag (maybe poorly named?) isn't for that

Comment: @Patrice I guess that is where my confusion comes from. The name is poorly chosen because that answer is one hell of a low quality answer :)

Answer (score 11):

If you think that an answer is wrong, or otherwise not a helpful answer to the question, then you should downvote it.  The VLQ flag is not there for answers that you think are bad answers, nor should answers that you think are wrong be deleted.  Answers are deleted when they aren't answers at all, not when you think they're bad answers.

Comment: Ok. In that case it's just a semantic issue then. His answer is very low quality, but in this case the "very low quality"-flag does not mean what one might guess but "not an answer" instead. Thanks

Comment: @Dbl The answer is low quality.  It's not *very* low quality, given the system's definition of those terms.  But yes, for an answer to meet the standard of Very Low Quality it needs to also be not an answer, that's how low the quality needs to be for it to be considered *very* low quality.

Comment: How are you distinguishing between low and very low? for me it is binary whether an answer is good or bad, the only thing inbetween is an effortless but correct answer. If the answer is so bad and missleading in concept that i am thinking "this person should not have answered at all" that's about as low quality to me as it gets. At least that is my view on it

Comment: @Dbl - I would argue that there really almost nothing wrong with that answer from *quality* point of view - it answers the question, has sensible formatting and reasonable amount of explanation text. Whether it actually represent good practice or not does not change the fact it is *answers* the question and written reasonably (so neither of  NAA/VLQ should apply).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok. i agree on NAA not applying. I guess distinguishing between Very low and low is subjective then. I read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer about this. I guess i'm just a strict person